# Javascript each line with different returns on submit using a form

Tags: javascript, html

**How to make each link on each line results different.**

Line 1 = `<a href="LINE 1 CONTENTS" target="_blank">Link - 01</a>`
Line 2 = `<a href="LINE 2 CONTENTS" target="_blank">Link - 02</a>`
Line 3 = `<a href="LINE 3 CONTENTS" target="_blank">Link - 03</a>`
Should only change the number on `Link - ??`
**The code below causes each input to have a different result. Just as it is in the javascript comment

But I would like to make a single input on separate lines do the same thing without being limited to creating new inputs if needed.**

```js
function submitted() {

  var link0 = (document.getElementsByName("link")[0].value).trim();
  // Should be removed. Only for demonstration: var link1= (document.getElementsByName("link")[1].value).trim(); 

  if (link0 != "") {
    link0 = '<a href="' + link0 + '" target="_blank">Link - 01</a>\n';
  }

  // Should be removed. Only for demonstration: if(link1!=""){ link1= '<a href="'+ link0 +'" target="_blank">Link - 02</a>\n';}

  var formValue = link0;
  document.getElementsByName("link")[1].value = formValue;
  return false;
}
```

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitted()">
  Field:<br><textarea name="link" style="height:200px"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="DONE"><br><br>
  <textarea name="link" style="height:200px"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a loop that iterates over all the inputs. Use a different name for the output field so it doesn't get included in the loop.

```js
function submitted() {

  var links = document.getElementsByName("link");
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.value = "";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].value.trim() != '') {
      output.value += `<a href="${links[i].value.trim()}" target="_blank">Link - ${i+1}</a>\n`;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitted()">
  Field:<br><textarea name="link" style="height:200px"></textarea><br>
  Field:<br><textarea name="link" style="height:200px"></textarea><br>
  Field:<br><textarea name="link" style="height:200px"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="DONE"><br><br>
  <textarea id="output" name="output" style="height:200px"></textarea>
</form>
```